# How to select a string that fits in the array then convert to string in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, scripting, data-conversion

I am trying to select a specific item that has a word `'Test'` in it from an array using Ruby. The output will then be converted to a string. Can someone tell me what have I missed?

**Script**

```
a = ['bTest', 'val', 'Ten']
a.select{ |o| o.include? 'Test' }.to_s
```

**Output**

```
["bTest"]
```

**My expected output**

```
'bTest'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.select` will select all items from an array for which the block is true. If you only want to select one item, then use `.detect` or `.find` (which are aliases):

```
a = ['bTest', 'val', 'Ten']
a.detect { |o| o.include? 'Test' }.to_s
# => "bTest"
```

Comment: hi, those were test ones but what if there's 2 or more. I wanted to output all of them and convert to a string instead. I've used the join command to merge them in a string. I wonder if there's more efficient way to do that? thanks.

Comment: If you want to select all strings that match, then `select` is indeed the method you want. That will always return an array even if there was 1 or 0 matches. At this point it's up to you what you want to do with the strings. If you want to join them together into a single string, then `join` is indeed the method you want.

Comment: @SiimLiiser you could use `Array#grep` if you prefer e.g. `a.grep(/Test/).join(' ')`

Comment: hello, the .detect is a good alternative for selecting one item only. I have accepted it as answer. thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to display the result:

```
a = ['bTest', 'val', 'Ten']
puts a.select{|o| o.include? 'Test' }
```